# R for loop, assigning incremental values for a new variable

Tags: r, for-loop, increment

I have some rows of 35,000. If the preventive_chem value is "Y", the value of prev_efficacy is 5,3,1 for the past 3 days and 10 to 1 for the next week. The sample output is below in img file.

```
Prev_Chem Date  prev_effi
0   7/3/2016    0   
0   7/4/2016    0   
0   7/5/2016    1   
0   7/6/2016    3   
Y   7/7/2016    5   
0   7/8/2016    10  
0   7/9/2016    9   
0   7/10/2016   8   
0   7/11/2016   7   
0   7/12/2016   6   
0   7/13/2016   5   
0   7/14/2016   4   
0   7/15/2016   3   
0   7/16/2016   2   
0   7/17/2016   1
0   7/18/2016   0
0   7/19/2016   0
```

If the preventive_chem value is 0, the prev_efficacy value is 0.

When I try this code,

```
*df$PreventEffic <- rep(0,nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
   {
     if(df$Preventive_Chem1[i] == "Y") 
       {   
       df$PreventEffic[i] <- 5
       df$PreventEffic[i-2] <- 1
       df$PreventEffic[i-1] <- 3
       df$PreventEffic[i+1] <- 10
       df$PreventEffic[i+2] <- 9
       df$PreventEffic[i+3] <- 8
       df$PreventEffic[i+4] <- 7
       df$PreventEffic[i+5] <- 6
       df$PreventEffic[i+6] <- 5
       df$PreventEffic[i+7] <- 4
       df$PreventEffic[i+8] <- 3
       df$PreventEffic[i+9] <- 2
       df$PreventEffic[i+10] <- 1
       }
     }*
```

It will take lot of time to run the code and return value 0 to 1016321 rows. Is there any efficient method to handle this issue without using "for loop".

Comment: In the future, please always dput your sample data, e.g. `dput(df)` so that we can just copy and paste your data, but before doing so, fix the inconsistency with your naming convention -- why are the colnames of df different in your if statement?  `Prev_Chem` vs. `Preventive_Chem1`.  I provide a solution below.

Comment: Do we need to consider any overlaps between the number assignments? That is, will there be incidents of 2 Ys with the +10 and -3 range of Prev_Chem?

Comment: Teenu Ss, I strongly suggest you accept @R.S.'s answer but consider the corner-case of a late `Y`, as my answer and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the structure of your data frame is consistent -- that is there are 2 days before and 10 days after the occurrence of Y then you do not need a for loop, simply find the indices of the "Y" and use this to assign values for each +/- days:

```
indx <- which(df$Prev_Chem == "Y")
df$PreventEffic <- rep(0,nrow(df))
df$PreventEffic[indx] <- 5
df$PreventEffic[indx-2] <- 1
df$PreventEffic[indx-1] <- 3
df$PreventEffic[indx+1] <- 10
df$PreventEffic[indx+2] <- 9
df$PreventEffic[indx+3] <- 8
df$PreventEffic[indx+4] <- 7
df$PreventEffic[indx+5] <- 6
df$PreventEffic[indx+6] <- 5
df$PreventEffic[indx+7] <- 4
df$PreventEffic[indx+8] <- 3
df$PreventEffic[indx+9] <- 2
df$PreventEffic[indx+10] <- 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much R.s!!!!!!!!! ur code helped me heaps....I noted ur point of dput(df)... Will do that next time. Also, naming disambiguation occurs bcoz of my laziness and space constraint there. I have one doubt. When I execute the code, return "value 0" to 1016321 rows in the PreventEffic column, though I have only 35,000 rows. How to rectify it... Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide the exact code you ran to retrurn "value 0"?

Comment: Hi R.s. I am sorry, as I made a mistake when I selecting the rows in dataframe.. Thanks for your solution. helped me a lot....No errors now...

Comment: Hi.. I have another issue arising for this week, (my input file similar as r2evans created). The value of 1 is in 5th row and 20th row for X, in r2evans code.... In my data file, it has 1 in 5 row and 10 th row. So the values of y have to reassign in the same pattern.. If the collision occurs in Y value, the biggest of the value to be considered. I tried for the past one day..but couldnt find solution. so please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the major inefficiencies in your code:

1. Pre-calculate where the interesting rows are, all at once. Instead of looping row-by-row, just do a vectorized comparison.
2. Since you are assigning a fixed vector of numbers to a swath of locations immediately surrounding each matching row, you can make assignments in vectors as well.

A first-cut (but naïve) implementation could be:

```
n <- 32
df <- data.frame(x = rep(0, n), y = 0)
df$x[c(5,20)] <- 1
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ y: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

for (i in which(df$x == 1))
  df$y[i + -2:10] <- c(1,3,5,10:1)
df
#    x  y
# 1  0  0
# 2  0  0
# 3  0  1
# 4  0  3
# 5  1  5
# 6  0 10
# 7  0  9
# 8  0  8
# 9  0  7
# 10 0  6
# 11 0  5
# 12 0  4
# 13 0  3
# 14 0  2
# 15 0  1
# 16 0  0
# 17 0  0
# 18 0  1
# 19 0  3
# 20 1  5
# 21 0 10
# 22 0  9
# 23 0  8
# 24 0  7
# 25 0  6
# 26 0  5
# 27 0  4
# 28 0  3
# 29 0  2
# 30 0  1
# 31 0  0
# 32 0  0
```

but one should quickly wonder what will happen when there is something interesting less than 10 rows from the bottom of the data.frame. Namely, you'll likely see an error similar to:

```
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = c(0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 10, 9,  : 
#   replacement has 30 rows, data has 28
```

Then you can try this (please forgive the heinous variable naming):

```
for (i in which(df$x == 1)) {
  j <- c(-2:0, head(1:10, n = dfn - i))
  k <- c(1,3,5, head(10:1, n = dfn - i))
  df$y[i + j] <- k
}
```

The `head(..., n=dfn-i)` is what ensures that we never have more replacement data than we have pre-existing rows to modify.

Comment: @R.S.'s answer has an advantage over mine, though it will fall prey to "too few rows" if you aren't careful. There are ways to mitigate this and still use his solution. To really know for certain, you'll need a benchmark. To do that well, you need actual data or more-representative data than I've chosen to use here. My guess is that the other answer will be an order or two faster than this ...

Comment: Nice! a solution without assuming existence of events after Y. Ha! was commenting at the same time, but yes, the solution I provided has assumptions about the structure of the data.

Comment: The best solution is probably to use your answer for all but those that occur in the last 10 rows (i.e., filter out `indx > (nrow(df)-10)`, then use a variant of my `head(...)` technique for those.

Comment: Thanks r2evans for your detailed description. your logic is so good.